# run callback function with its parent in jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate, fadein, jquery-callback

I want to run animations for the links (q2 ul li a) while showing (q2) in same time, q2 will be hidden on page load.

```
$('.q2').fadeIn(function(){
$('.q2 ul li a').animate({ borderSpacing : 1 }, {
    step: function(now,fx) {
    $(this).css('-webkit-transform','rotate('+(-1*200*now+200)+'deg) scale('+(now)+')'); 
    $(this).css('-moz-transform','rotate('+(-1*200*now+200)+'deg) scale('+(now)+')');
    $(this).css('transform','rotate('+(-1*200*now+200)+'deg) scale('+(now)+')');    
    },
    duration:1500 }, 'linear')
});
});
```

and in css :

```
ul li a {
    border-spacing: 0;
}
```

Comment: Please explain whats not working here? Also it would be great if you can put the same in jsfiddle.

Comment: There is'nt any error here. but because .q2 is display: none at first, I must to write show() or fadeIn() function for it,so the links will be shown without any animation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code, animation will be execute after `$('.q2')` visible because you put this animation in the callback of fadeIn function. Maybe it should like this:

```
$('.q2').fadeIn(1500);
$('.q2 ul li a').animate({ borderSpacing : 1 }, {
    step: function(now,fx) {
        $(this).css('-webkit-transform','rotate('+(-1*200*now+200)+'deg) scale('+(now)+')'); 
        $(this).css('-moz-transform','rotate('+(-1*200*now+200)+'deg) scale('+(now)+')');
        $(this).css('transform','rotate('+(-1*200*now+200)+'deg) scale('+(now)+')');    
    },
    duration:1500 }, 
    'linear')
});
```